# Excluding default valued elements in XML output of Jersey RESTful API with JAXB

Tags: xml, jaxb, jersey, marshalling, xmladapter

I'm using JAXB to serialize objects to XML. I want to exclude elements with default values in my response. While serializing objects to JSON i have used [JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_DEFAULT](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#NON_DEFAULT) in the ObjectMapper configuration to exclude default values.

```
SerializationConfig sc = objectMapper.getSerializationConfig()
       .withSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_DEFAULT);
objectMapper.setSerializationConfig(sc);
```

I want same behavior for XML response also.
How can i do this?

Comment: Use the boxed types instead of primitives. JAXB should exclude nulls by default. And change Jackson to exclude nulls instead of defaults. Not much else you can do. I don't think JAXB is as smart as you need it to be to get your desired behavior.